# Node.JS version is different when trying to install angular cli

Tags: node.js, installation, angular-cli

I can't figure this one out and have been googling and searching for some time now to no avail.

From the command prompt the issue should be pretty obvious here,

[image: pic]

How can I easily clear this up? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the output of `where ng`? I suspect you're running an `ng` that was installed globally into the directory of an older Node version

Comment: @Codebling--- here it is.... C:\Users\--->where ng
C:\tools\nodejs\ng
C:\tools\nodejs\ng.cmd
C:\Users\--\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
C:\Users\--\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I did a where node command in the command prompt and it pointed me to another node version that I had downloaded previously it appears. I deleted that one out and redid everything and now its looking good.